# Is there such thing as global functions in AngularJS? [see code]

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-scope, single-page-application

We have finally decided to use Angular at work and I was asked to develop a little prototype to see what AngularJS is capable of.

We have a gradeController.js file where we have the following code:

```
var gradeControllers = angular.module('gradeControllers', []);

gradeControllers.controller('GradeListController', ['$scope', '$http',
    function ($scope, $http) {
        $http({
            method: 'GET',
            url: '/api/grades',
            params: {
                skip: 0,
                take: 1000
            }
        }).success(function (data) {
            $scope.grades = data.splice(0, 150);
            $(".loader").hide();
        });

        $scope.saveChanges = function (grade) {
            alert("SAVING CHANGES...");
            $scope.gradeValue = grade.gradeValue;
            $scope.comment = grade.comment;
            $http({
                method: 'PUT',
                url: '/api/grades',
                params: {
                    id: grade.gradeId,
                    gradeValue: grade.gradeValue
                }
            }).success(function () {
                window.location.href = "#/grades";
            }).fail(function () {
                alert('FAIL');
            });
        };

    $scope.orderProp = 'dateModified';
}]);

gradeControllers.controller('GradeDetailController', ['$scope', '$routeParams', '$http',
    function($scope, $routeParams, $http) {
        $http({
            method: 'GET',
            url: '/api/grades/' + $routeParams.gradeId,
        }).success(function (data) {
            $scope.grade = data;
            $("form").show();
            $(".loader").hide();
        });

        $scope.saveChanges = function (grade) {
            $scope.gradeValue = grade.gradeValue;
            $scope.comment = grade.comment;
            $http({
                method: 'PUT',
                url: '/api/grades',
                params: {
                    id: grade.gradeId,
                    gradeValue: grade.gradeValue
                }
            }).success(function () {
                window.location.href = "#/grades";
            }).fail(function() {
                alert('FAIL');
            });
        };
    }
]);
```

Now, as you can see we have duplicated `saveChanges()` function in both controllers and that is what is bothering us.

Would it be possible to almost inject the `$scope` and `$http` when defining the module and put the `saveChanges()` function outside of the controllers? Something like the following:

```
var gradeControllers = angular.module('gradeControllers', ['$scope', '$http']);

$scope.saveChanges = function (grade) {
    $scope.gradeValue = grade.gradeValue;
    $scope.comment = grade.comment;
    $http({
        method: 'PUT',
        url: '/api/grades',
        params: {
            id: grade.gradeId,
            gradeValue: grade.gradeValue
        }
    }).success(function () {
        window.location.href = "#/grades";
    }).fail(function () {
        alert('FAIL');
    });
};

gradeControllers.controller('GradeListController', [,
    function ($scope, $http) {
        $http({
            method: 'GET',
            url: '/api/grades',
            params: {
                skip: 0,
                take: 1000
            }
        }).success(function (data) {
            $scope.grades = data.splice(0, 150);
            $(".loader").hide();
        });

        $scope.saveChanges();

    $scope.orderProp = 'dateModified';
}]);

gradeControllers.controller('GradeDetailController', ['$routeParams',
    function($scope, $routeParams, $http) {
        $http({
            method: 'GET',
            url: '/api/grades/' + $routeParams.gradeId,
        }).success(function (data) {
            $scope.grade = data;
            $("form").show();
            $(".loader").hide();
        });

        $scope.saveChanges();

    }
]);
```

We usually call `saveChanges()` by using

`<input id="saveChanges" type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" ng-click="saveChanges(grade)" text="Save changes" />`

so I believe(am hoping) that if we put the `saveChanges()` outside of the controllers it will still know what the scope is.

Please let me know if you need any clarification and I hope someone more experienced than myself can help us with this issue

Comment: Take a look at `services` - I'd say that's what you're looking for. (http://docs.angularjs.org/guide/dev_guide.services.understanding_services)

Comment: You should not touch the $scope in your save method, and then you can mode the method into a service.

Comment: Just having a look at services. I think you guys are right - they seem to be exactly what we need. @ThorJacobsen would you mind writing your comment as an answer so I can select it as the right answer? Unless anyone case anyone else has other ideas/suggestions?

Comment: Feel free to accept or wait for more comments :) That's just what I'd do ;)

Comment: I will wait a few more minutes give other people a chance as well but you seem to know what you are talking about so no reason why I can't accept it :) Thank you @ThorJacobsen (do you have any superpowers by the way? :P)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One option is to create your own service

```
app.service('util', ['$http', [function () {
 this.util = {
    _saveChanges = function (scope, grade) {
            scope.gradeValue = grade.gradeValue;
            scope.comment = grade.comment;
            $http({
                method: 'PUT',
                url: '/api/grades',
                params: {
                    id: grade.gradeId,
                    gradeValue: grade.gradeValue
                }
            }).success(function () {
                window.location.href = "#/grades";
            }).fail(function() {
                alert('FAIL');
            });
        }
    }

    var self = this.util;
    return {
        saveChanges: this.util._saveChanges
    }
}]);
```

and you can include this service to yours controller

```
var gradeControllers = angular.module('gradeControllers', ['$scope', '$http', 'util']);
gradeControllers.controller('GradeListController', [,
    function ($scope, $http, util) {
        $scope.saveChanges = util.saveChanges;
        ...
    }]);
```

and call will be

```
$scope.saveChanges($scope, grade)
```

where you pass current $scope and grade

Comment: if I was to take the above approach where would I have to define the service? Would is still be in the gradeController.js file? Or in a separate file?

Comment: Its better to have separate file.

Comment: You need to include this file in your "index.html" file (or whatever is called your base html page), same as you did for the controller.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at `services` - I'd say that's what you're looking for. (http://docs.angularjs.org/guide/dev_guide.services.understanding_services)